# Hover with Javascript (namespace)

Tags: javascript, namespaces, hover

With the use of namespace, i'm trying to make a div-element in Javascript where if you hover over the div it'll change color and change back when not hovering over it. Please help!

Comment: Can you show us what you did try? And where you got stuck?

Comment: Hi, this is not a `code for me` site. Have you tried anything? show us your code, and we'll gladly help you

Comment: What does "with the use of namespace" mean?

Comment: The thing is, i've written a code for it and it works properly. But then i saw that i need to do it with the help of namespace. And i don't understand what that means. That's why i'm asking here. I'm not looking for you to write me the thing, i'm just asking to get a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Where did you see that? What did it say exactly? It doesn't make any sense out of context. If someone wants you to use namespaces, you'll have to ask what they mean because JS doesn't have namespaces, only approximations with objects etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? There is many ways to do it, I used plain js. The css you put whetever you want.

I don't understand what the namespace means in your situation.

Following are the respective javascript, css and html. But things like this you can google and find the parts that you need.

```js
function changeColors(){
 if(document.getElementById("myElement").classList.contains('class1')){
  document.getElementById("myElement").classList.remove('class1');
    document.getElementById("myElement").classList.add('class2');  
 }else{
  document.getElementById("myElement").classList.remove('class2');
    document.getElementById("myElement").classList.add('class1');
 }
}
```

```css
.class1{
  color:red;
}

.class2{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3 id="myElement" class="class1" onmouseover="changeColors()"
  onmouseout="changeColors()">
    Hello
  </h3>
</div>
```